# Assignment rule to distribute matrix-multiplication over custom notation

Tags: assignment, custom-notation

I'm trying to write some code to do basic algebraic manipulations in BraKet notation.

Thus far I have a function **KetToVec** which will convert any expression of the form *a1 Ket[s1]+ b Ket[s2] +...* to a column vector, and the inverse function **VecToKet** which does the reverse. One problem I'm having is in assigning matrix multiplication rules to the Ket form of the vectors.

Currently I have

```
Ket:/Dot[M_?MatrixQ,Ket[s__]]:= VecToKet[M.KetToVec[Ket[s]]]
```

which works for a single Ket. However I can't figure out how to make a similar assignment for multiplication to distribute over a linear combination of Ket's without having to overload one of the internal functions Times, Plus or Dot.

What I want is a way for it to evaluate

```
X.(a*Ket[s]) := a*(X.Ket[s])
```

and hence in general

```
X.(a*Ket[s1]+ b*Ket[s2]+..) := a*(X.Ket[s1]) + b*(X.Ket[s2])+...
```

But if I try something like

```
Ket:/Dot[M_?MatrixQ,Times[a_,Ket[s__]]]:= a*VecToKet[M.KetToVec[Ket[s]]]
```

it returns the error message *"Tag Ket in ... is too deep for an assignment rule to be found"*

Is this possible?
Cheers!

Comment: FWIW, you might also want to check out: http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/

Comment: @tkott That's a good link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible directly, at least as far as I know. The error message you are getting is just a manifestation of it. You are using `UpValues`, which have a fundamental limitation that they can only be attached to symbols on a level no deeper than 1. I discussed this more in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648260/what-does-upvalue-mean-in-mathematica-and-when-to-use-them).

Redefining built-in functions, OTOH, especially such fundamental ones as `Plus`, `Times` and `Dot`, is a bad idea most of the time. What you can do, is to create a lexical environment, where they will be replaced by some functions `myPlus`, `myTimes`, and `myDot`:

```
ClearAll[env];
SetAttributes[env,HoldAll];
env[code_]:= 
 With[{rules = {Times->myTimes,Plus->myPlus,dot->myDot}},
  Unevaluated[code]/.rules/.Reverse[rules,{2}]
 ]
```

Now, for example, you can define (note that in the first definition, `s` comes with a blank `_`, which you missed):

```
ClearAll[myDot];
myDot[M_, myTimes[a_, Ket[s_]]] := 
   myTimes[a, VecToKet[myDot[M, KetToVec[Ket[s]]]]];
myDot[M_, myPlus[args__]] := 
   myPlus @@ Map[myDot[M, #] &, {args}];
```

And you use this as

```
env[X.(a*Ket[s])]
```

> `a VecToKet[X.KetToVec[Ket[s]]]`

and also

```
env[X.(a*Ket[s1] + b*Ket[s2])]
```

> `a VecToKet[X.KetToVec[Ket[s1]]] + b VecToKet[X.KetToVec[Ket[s2]]]`

The function `env` serves as a [custom evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747742/uses-for-mapall/5756641#5756641) here. The disadvantage of this approach is that you will generally have to insert `env` everywhere in your code, because `env` binds lexically rather than dynamically. But as long as the operation of `Times`, `Plus` and `Dot` on your objects is simply undefined (which would be so for general symbolic objects), you may avoid this problem by replacing the simple implementation above with a more complex infinite-evaluation one:

```
ClearAll[env];
SetAttributes[env, HoldAll];
env[code_] :=
  With[{result = 
      With[{rules = {Times -> myTimes, Plus -> myPlus, Dot -> myDot}},
         Unevaluated[code] /. rules /. Reverse[rules, {2}]
      ]},
     env[result] /; result =!= Unevaluated[code]
  ]; 
env[code_] := code;
```

which should also cover composition.

Finally, you can, if you wish, use `$Pre` to avoid typing `env` every time you compute things interactively: `$Pre = env`;

Comment: For some reason while using the last environment the expression didn't evaluate correctly. To get it to work I had to use the following definitions:

Comment: (Sorry, didn't relise pressing return posted the comment) Thanks for the answer! It seems that while using the last environment the expression doesn't evaluate correctly unless I use the following definitions: `ClearAll[myDot];
myDot[M_, Ket[s__]] := VecToKet[M.KetToVec[Ket[s]]];
myDot[M_, myTimes[a_, Ket[s__]]] := 
  myTimes[a, VecToKet[Dot[M, KetToVec[Ket[s]]]]];
myDot[M_?MatrixQ, myPlus[args__]] := 
  myPlus @@ Map[myDot[M, #] &, {args}];`. Replacing the 'Dot' with 'myDot' in the 1st and 2nd definitions above results in errors in the VecToKet function I have.